# Error deploying Grails Portlet on Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to deploy a grails application as Liferay portlet. I'm using Liferay6 bundled with tomcat7. When I try to deploy the war I got:

```
06:32:36,394 ERROR [GrailsDispatcherServlet:470] Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Grails requires a parent ApplicationContext, is the /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file missing?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Apr 30, 2014 6:32:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Grails requires a parent ApplicationContext, is the /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file missing?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Apr 30, 2014 6:32:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /liferayPortelt-0.1 threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Grails requires a parent ApplicationContext, is the /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file missing?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

ApplicationContext file already exist in my application. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing grails's [webxml](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) plugin.

Shashank

Comment: I tried that @SA13, but that did not fix it. How do i go about debugging this issue? I was on the irc, but it was quiet about this issue.

Comment: Can you please list the plugins & dependencies of your app i.e. in BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: FWIW: I believe this has something to do with setting up and accepting the license agreement. Once I did that, the marketplace-portlet gets installed to share the application context. At least thats what worked for me. Hth.